# Is there a way to trigger a function in an express app on terminate?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Basically I want a syntax like:

```
app.on("event:terminate", dumpFunc);
```

So that if the server is stopped for any reason I can dump data to disk.

Is there a way to do this, or should I stick to logging everything in a database every few seconds with a `setTimeout`?

Like:

```
var badIdea = setTimeout(dumpFunc, 5000);

function dumpFunc(stuff){
    //Do stuff
    badIdea = setTimeout(dumpFunc, 5000);
}
```

I'm open to any suggestions on this, but I need the state of the variables at the time of a crash to persist on the next load. And while I agree, don't crash is probably the best course of action, it's unavoidable at the moment.

specifically I need to protect during either

1. a `SIGINT`/`SIGKILL` to `node` from the server (`CTRL`+`C` type event)
2. User input that doesn't conform to expectations and crashes the server when it looks for a property of `undefined` or `NaN`

In theory I could wrap the whole codebase in a `try`/`catch` block to protect against the latter, but sometimes we get looping conditions (I know, I know, test), or other issues and the process needs to be terminated.

I'm not expecting something to miraculously back us up in the event of a power outage or disk failure, but we need some kind of graceful termination options, so I'm all ears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run your entire application in a [Domain](http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html), so you can catch errors. It works similarly to catching uncaught exceptions, and is equally bad in terms of not restarting the process (process will leak resources, etc).

```
var domain = require('domain');
var d = domain.create();
d.on('error', function(err) {
  // log the error, store it, etc
});
d.run(function() {
  var express = require('express');
  var app = express();

  // application code here

  app.listen();
});
```

To catch a `SIGINT`, you'd do something like this:

```
process.on('SIGINT', function() {
  // caught an interrupt signal
});
```

As for `SIGKILL`, it is a signal that cannot be caught.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following code:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    console.log("Error packing", err);
});
```

It will make your app uncrashable. However, I don't think that will keep you from a kill signal.

Comment: thanks! you were on the right track, node's [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_exit) have a `sigint` event too! This is excellent reading.